# Bitstrings of length n which the first three bits are not equal using complement

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> For any integer $n ≥ 3$, let $B_n$ be the number of bitstrings of length $n$ in which the first three bits are not all equal. Which of the following is true?
>
> (a) $B_n = 2 \cdot 2^{n-3}$
>   **(b) $B_n = 6 \cdot 2^{n-3}$**
>   (c) $B_n = 2^{n} - 2$
>   (d) $B_n = 2^{n} - 6$

I can see that it is **(b)** because the number of ways for bitstrings of length $3$ to not have all equal bits is the same as $2^{n} - 2$ which removes the bitstrings $111$ and $000$, meaning there are $6$ possible ways for bitstrings whose first $3$ bits are not equal. Now, we choose the remaining $n-3$ by doing $2^{n-3}$ which comes out to $B_n = 6 \cdot 2^{n-3}$.

**My Question:**
What if I wanted to take the complement and calculate it that way? What am I doing wrong? This is my answer:

There are $2$ ways that a bitstring can start with $3$ equal bits:

1. $111$ followed by $n-3$ arbitrary bits, and
2. $000$ followed by $n-3$ arbitrary bits.

There are two ways to do this, so:

$2 \cdot 2^{n-3} = 2^{n-2}$

Subtract this from all bitstrings of length $n$ to get all bitstrings that do not start with $111$ or $000$:

$2^{n} - 2 \cdot 2^{n-3}$
$= 2^{n} - 2^{n-2}$
$\ldots$
$= 3 \cdot 2^{n-2}$

Comment: Notice that $3 \cdot 2^{n - 2} = 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 2^{n - 3} = 6 \cdot 2^{n - 3}$.

Comment: Just realized I had over simplified. Woops!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I got was the same, however it was over simplified:

$3 \cdot 2^{n-2} = 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 2^{n-2} = 6 \cdot 2^{n-3}$

Thank you @NFTaussig.